# Spacer rings and teleconverters

Tags: teleconverter

I won't mention brand names to made the question as generic as possible.

If I have a camera with zoom, and I want to add a certain teleconverter lens, do I need to put in-between a spacer ring, to get the correct magnification factor (i.e. for other reasons than adapting the diameters or distancing the TC from the full extended zoom)?

If so, how does the spacer ring *length* affect the resulting optics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the magnification factor is independent of the distance ("correct" is in the eye of the beholder, the magnification factor is usually indicative).

If the ring is too thick you may introduce vignetting (of course if you are adapting a large converter to a smaller lens this likely doesn't come into play).

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I should have used a different adjective than 'correct', maybe 'listed' would  fit better?